# Deploying Docpad to Modulus in Production

Tags: json, node.js, deployment, coffeescript, docpad

I am wanting to know how to go about deploying my [docpad](http://docpad.org/docs/deploy) project to [modulus](https://modulus.io/codex/getting_started).

Assuming I need to be running in production mode to do so. I noticed for the static deployment on docpad you just upload the contents of the out directory. If we are using a node server do we upload the entire project direcory. Which I did try but I don't think my docpad.coffee settings were correct. You can see below my attempt at this.

### docpad.coffee

```
    # ----------------
    # Server Configuration
    # Server Express
    # ----------------
    # The express.js instance that we want DocPad to use
    # If not set, we will create our own
    serverExpress: default



    # ----------------
    # Port
    # ----------------
    # Use to change the port that DocPad listens to
    # By default we will detect the appropriate port number for our environment
    # if no environment port number is detected we will use 9778 as the port number
    # Checked environment variables are:
    # - PORT - Heroku, Nodejitsu, Custom
    # - VCAP_APP_PORT - AppFog
    # - VMC_APP_PORT - CloudFoundry
    port: - PORT
```

The First step according to the modulus site is to *Use the environment variable PORT. app.listen(process.env.PORT)* I assumed that would meant adding the `- PORT` to the **docpad.coffee** file.

As well I am not even sure how to have the site run in production when uploaded, remember I am just uploading the entire directory. Do I run a command from the Modulus server in terminal once the project is deployed?

Modulus also asks  for the following in my packages.json file. I had most of them already except for the `"main": "path/to/custom_main.js"` which I assumed was the docpad.coffee file, so I linked to that.

### Package.json

```
    {
  "name": "zurb-foundation.docpad",
  "version": "0.4.0",
  "description": "Zurb Foundation skeleton for DocPad. Simple and flexible HTML, CSS, and Javascript for popular user interface components and interactions.",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/axyz/zurb-foundation.docpad",
  "keywords": [
    "docpad-skeleton",
    "docpad",
    "website",
    "foundation",
    "zurb foundation"
  ],
  "author": "Andrea Moretti <axyzxp@gmail.com>",
  "maintainers": [
    "Andrea Moretti <axyzxp@gmail.com>"
  ],
  "contributors": [
    "Andrea Moretti <axyzxp@gmail.com>"
  ],
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/axyz/zurb-foundation.docpad/issues"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "http://github.com/axyz/zurb-foundation.docpad.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10",
    "npm": "1.3"
  },
  "main": "docpad.coffee",
  "dependencies": {
    "docpad": "~6.54.1",
    "docpad-plugin-eco": "~2.0.2",
    "docpad-plugin-livereload": "~2.5.3",
    "docpad-plugin-coffeescript": "~2.2.2",
    "express" : "2.5.x",
    "ejs" : "0.8.x",
    "docpad-plugin-nodesass": "~2.1.1"
  },
  "main": "node_modules/docpad/bin/docpad-server",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node_modules/docpad/bin/docpad-server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

When I Deployed the site it did not work at all, I mean I had a link but the site didnt work. Any suggestions on what to do when deploying a docpad site to Modulus? I used the skeleton Foundation with Sass as well after installing docpad, which did work locally.

Ok still trying to get this thing working, when I run the site now it works locally, and when I deploy it I get a link to a modulus subdomian that doesnt work. I went and checked the logs on the modulus site and this is what I get

### Modulus Logs

...

```
docpad-plugin-coffeescript@2.2.2 node_modules/docpad-plugin-coffeescript
└── coffee-script@1.6.3

docpad-plugin-eco@2.0.2 node_modules/docpad-plugin-eco
└── eco@1.1.0-rc-3 (strscan@1.0.1, coffee-script@1.6.3)

express@2.5.11 node_modules/express
├── qs@0.4.2
├── mime@1.2.4
├── mkdirp@0.3.0
└── connect@1.9.2 (formidable@1.0.14)

docpad-plugin-livereload@2.5.3 node_modules/docpad-plugin-livereload
├── extendr@2.1.0 (typechecker@2.0.8)
├── primus@1.4.4 (extendable@0.0.6, load@1.0.0)
└── ws@0.4.31 (tinycolor@0.0.1, options@0.0.5, commander@0.6.1, nan@0.3.2)

docpad@6.54.4 node_modules/docpad
├── lazy-require@1.0.0
├── eachr@2.0.2
├── extendr@2.1.0
├── extract-opts@2.2.0
├── caterpillar-filter@2.0.3
├── envfile@1.0.0
├── getmac@1.0.6
├── commander@2.0.0
├── ambi@2.1.6
├── typechecker@2.0.8
├── taskgroup@3.3.0
├── mime@1.2.11
├── query-engine@1.5.3
├── bal-util@2.3.2
├── safefs@3.0.3 (taskgroup@3.2.4)
├── semver@2.2.1
├── safeps@2.2.8 (taskgroup@3.2.4)
├── caterpillar-human@2.1.1 (ansistyles@0.1.1, ansicolors@0.2.1)
├── progressbar@1.0.3 (progress@1.1.2)
├── event-emitter-grouped@2.3.1 (taskgroup@3.2.4)
├── watchr@2.4.4 (taskgroup@3.2.4)
├── promptly@0.2.0 (read@1.0.5)
├── backbone@1.1.0 (underscore@1.5.2)
├── jschardet@1.1.0
├── superagent@0.15.7 (methods@0.0.1, cookiejar@1.3.0, debug@0.7.3, qs@0.6.5, emitter-component@1.0.0, reduce-component@1.0.1, mime@1.2.5, formidable@1.0.14)
├── lodash@2.2.1
├── cson@1.4.5 (requirefresh@1.1.2, coffee-script@1.6.3, js2coffee@0.2.3)
├── caterpillar@2.0.6 (readable-stream@1.1.9)
├── encoding@0.1.7 (iconv-lite@0.2.11)
├── yamljs@0.1.4 (glob@3.1.21, argparse@0.1.15)
└── express@3.4.4 (methods@0.1.0, range-parser@0.0.4, cookie-signature@1.0.1, fresh@0.2.0, debug@0.7.3, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, cookie@0.1.0, send@0.1.4, mkdirp@0.3.5, commander@1.3.2, connect@2.11.0)

docpad-plugin-nodesass@2.1.1 node_modules/docpad-plugin-nodesass
├── node-neat@1.0.0
├── node-bourbon@1.0.0
├── taskgroup@3.2.4 (ambi@2.1.6)
└── node-sass@0.7.0 (node-watch@0.3.4, colors@0.6.0-1, mkdirp@0.3.5, optimist@0.6.0, mocha@1.13.0)
INFO: Main file specified in package.json: node_modules/docpad/bin/docpad-server
INFO: Starting application.
[32minfo:[39m Welcome to DocPad v6.54.4 (global installation: /mnt/data/2/node_modules/docpad)
[32minfo:[39m Contribute: http://docpad.org/docs/contribute
[32minfo:[39m Plugins: 
[32minfo:[39m Environment: production
[32minfo:[39m DocPad listening to http://localhost:8080/ on directory /mnt/data/2/node_modules/docpad/bin/out
[32minfo:[39m Generating...
[33mnotice:[39m DocPad is currently running without any plugins installed. You probably want to install some: http://docpad.org/plugins
Error: Cannot generate website as the src dir was not found
    at /mnt/data/2/node_modules/docpad/out/lib/docpad.js:3102:21
    at /mnt/data/2/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/safefs/out/lib/safefs.js:185:16
    at Object.cb [as oncomplete] (fs.js:168:19)
[2013-11-03T17:19:32.095Z] Application initialized with pid 69363
```

The entire log file can be seen here https://gist.github.com/kitsondevelopment/7292623

It says it cant find the src directory however the source directory is there according to this screen shot so I do not understand.

[image]

### Update

I just noticed that the error it is referring to the src directory in the node_modules/docpad directory, my app created with `docpad run` did not have a src directory in node_modules/docpad. WHy might this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

It appears that modulus does something odd when just using package.json to set docpad as the entry point.  My guess is that it doesn't set the current directory correctly.

I got it working by creating an app.js that just hands off execution to docpad (similar to the [deployment instructions](http://docpad.org/docs/deploy) for AppFog:

```
module.exports = require(__dirname+'/node_modules/docpad/out/bin/docpad-server');
```

Then in package.json, I pointed `main` at  `app.js`

```
"engines" : {
    "node": "0.10",
    "npm": "1.2"
},
"dependencies": {
    ... the dependencies from the skeleton ...
},
"main": "app.js",
```

===

You shouldn't set `serverExpress` at all.  Remove that set of lines.  You also shouldn't set `port`. The `port` setting in docpad.coffee is only if you want to hard code a specific port (which you don't).  docpad will automatically look at all of the environment variables typically used by node hosts (including the one that Modulus is setting) and will figure out the correct port without you doing anything special.

Comment: sorry I should have included my entire package.json file. Those lines were already in it. I will inlcude my entire code now.

Comment: Also what about the port in the docpad coffee file, what I am doing just does not seem right.

Comment: Edited to add the port issue. You have `main` in the package.json twice.  Once with `docpad.coffee` which is wrong, and once with `docpad-server` which is correct.  Remove the `docpad.coffee` one.

Comment: P.S.  You can't set `serverExpress: default` as that is not valid.  If you want default behavior (which you do), then don't set anything at all. I'd recommend you go read up on CoffeeScript to understand the syntax of docpad.coffee.  It's an actual code file and your customizations are causing errors.

Comment: Also, as a general rule, you should be able to run `docpad run` on your local machine successfully before you bother trying to upload something to Modulus.  If it doesn't work on your own machine, it won't work on Modulus. It's a lot easier to troubleshoot problems on your own machine, so I highly recommend always getting it working there first.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am still having some issues but I posted the logfiles above for Modulus, wondering if that helps.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanitory: "Cannot generate website as the src dir was not found".  You didn't appear to upload the src directory.

Comment: the src directory is there I added a screenshot above showing this.

Comment: live-reload plugin doesn't work if started in this manner (via `npm start` where it simply points to `app.js`). live-reload works fine with `docpad run` on the same project.